# Flutter / Dart - change colour of TextField isn't working

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I have now got 9 TextField's or at least I think they are TextField's.  I am trying to change the colour/background colour of them.  So on one I added the line "fillColor: Colors.green)," in the hope this would turn the background of the TextField green, but nothing has changed.  Have I put this in the incorrect place or used the incorrect command? Also once I have the colour can I change it depending on the input number, for example below 5 it would be red, between 5.1 and 9 it would be green and 9.1 or above its orange?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with diabetic dosage for a meal!';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";
  String result3 = "0";

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
        numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR2C2controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR3() {
    if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) *
            double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
        numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Target Level',
                          hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                          fillColor: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'One Unit',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Drop by',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Ratio',
                        hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

LATEST UPDATE after help from eamirho3ein
This is the new code, input 1 does change colour as it should, but so does input 2 on reaction to input 1 input. If I change the calculation to numR1C2controller instead of numR1C1controller (on the 3 lines), the colour changing just stops working.

```
_calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
        numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    } else if (numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with diabetic dosage for a meal!';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  Color _fillColor = Colors.white;
  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";
  String result3 = "0";

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
        numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    } else if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR2C2controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR3() {
    if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) *
            double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
        numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      controller: numR1C1controller,
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Target Level',
                          hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                          fillColor: _fillColor,
                          filled: true),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                          filled: true,
                          labelText: 'Current Level',
                          hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                          fillColor: _fillColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'One Unit',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Drop by',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Ratio',
                        hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order `fillColor` works you need to set `filled` to `true`:

```
decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Target Level',
      hintText: 'Enter First Number',
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      filled: true,//<--- add this
    ),
```

for your **next issue** you need define new variable outside the build method like this:

```
Color _fillColor = Colors.white;
```

then use it like this:

```
TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        controller: numR1C1controller,
        onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
        ],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Target Level',
            hintText: 'Enter First Number',
            fillColor: _fillColor,
            filled: true),
      )
```

and also change _calculateR1 to this:

```
_calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {

        double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
        numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
    }

    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you say in which textfield you want that background color condition ? @rnmuk

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, the color condition will just be for the "Enter Second Number" input please, but once I know how to do it I can add it to other fields if required.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work, I have added the "Color _fillColor = Colors.white;" line to line 4, which I assumed must be OK.  I then added the other suggestions, this seemed to work but does work on Input1 rather than input2.  So I thought it would be easy to change so simply updated the 3 lines that mention "numR1C1controller.text" (input 1) and updated to "numR1C2controller.text" but strangely it doesn't then work on input 2 and has the error "fillColor: _fillColor," with underlined in red "_fillColor" meaning Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)? I have added the new code above :

Comment: you need define _fillColor inside  _AddTwoNumbersState class.

Comment: this approach only works for one input, you can use same _fillColor in every input.

Comment: OK, so I have moved the line "Color _fillColor = Colors.white;" below the line "class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {" but the input 2 still has the error "fillColor: _fillColor," with underlined in red "_fillColor" meaning Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)? But from your last comment, once working, I could add the _fillColor in every input?

Comment: If you want to use variable for any field in `InputDecoration` you need to remove `const`before `InputDecoration`.

Comment: also remember if you want to use this for input 2, you need to move those logic in _calculateR1 to _calculateR2 and update with input two controller.

Comment: @rnmuk was it what you want?

Comment: Yes, your suggestions are what I want, just struggling to get it to work.  I have removed the "const" before "InputDecoration", which resolved the red underline problem. But even after changing the numR1C1controller to numR1C2controller, I can't get it working and it won't change the colour on the second input, still trying though.

Comment: could you update your question so I get where is the problem?

Comment: @rnmuk I updated my answer, that happened because first condition makes true all the time for input two. remember first if doesn't contain setstate, its value will be updated in next if.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm totally new to coding and struggling, so thanks for all your help.  If I copy your new updated code over the top it works fine for input 1 but input 2 is updated on the input of input 1.  If I then change the calculation part and update the 2 lines from numR1C1controller to numR1C2controller, I then get a Format exception when I try to enter a number into input 1.

Comment: I think I have sorted it, if I change the "filled: true" to "filled: false" on the first number input, it then works and only changes the background on the second input box! Thank you for all your help. As I'm quite new, can I give both @eamirho3ein and iocomxda credit or do I have to pick the best answer to tick?

Comment: glad to help. @rnmuk you can up vote both answers by clicking on up arrow near the answer. but you can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the background filled, you have to use `filled: true,`

If you also want the border to be green, you have to use `focusedBorder`. This way you are keeping the border grey when unfocused, but it becomes green when is focused.

```
TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.green),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Target Level',
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                        fillColor: Colors.green),
                  ),
```

Comment: Thank you @iocomxda

So looks like adding the "filled: true," line does then allow the "fillColor: Colors.green)," to work and then adding the "focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.green)," lines then adds an outline to the text box as you suggested. Yes the border doesn't appear until you click into the TextField

Comment: @rnmuk If helped, mark the answer as solution!